# How do I fix a broken brass drawer pull?

Tags: repair, furniture, drawers, fastening

[image: Brass Drawer Pull]

This drawer pull comes from an antique dresser; it mates with a threaded screw that goes inside the drawer.

The collar on the drawer pull has gradually become thinner and cracked, and no longer grabs the screw with sufficient force to pull the drawer out.

How would I repair this drawer pull (there are actually 7 with this problem across 2 dressers)?

Comment: How important is it to you to maintain the original pulls? I'd be inclined to simply replace them all with modern pulls that have a suitably antique look about them.

Comment: The dresser is an antique and is part of a set; roughly 90 years old, and there are roughly 17 drawer pulls in three different sizes, so that wouldn't be a great idea.

Comment: Then I'd go for brazing on new metal as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find some NOS (new old stock) pulls of the same type on eBay or Etsy. I recently did the same thing for an old writing desk that was missing one of the pulls. I couldn't find a match for the missing one, so I replaced the whole set.

If you want them repaired, then they will probably need to be brazed and re-tapped. That is a job that you should have done professionally if you aren't comfortable using a torch.

[Brazing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazing)

Comment: Perhaps you could cut the head off the screw (or a slightly longer one) epoxy the cut end into the the pull and attach to the drawer with a crown nut (no exposed thread to catch on stuff)

Comment: Bought the supplies to do this. Turns out that even in the 20s or 30s, one could get SAE #10-24 threaded screws.   I bought new ones, and they fit a little more tightly than the old ones... we'll see how they hold up.